# Différence entre un groupe pronominal et une subordonnée relative

Tags: grammaire, subordonnées, pronoms-relatifs

J'ai un exercice de grammaire dans lequel je dois identifier la nature et la fonction de groupe de mots. 
Voici deux cas qui m'embêtent et un cas (le #3) auquel je crois avoir bien répondu.

1. Les images exposées dans les revues **dont** les filles raffolent montrent toutes la même chose : une pubère filiforme au poids au dessous de la moyenne.
2. Moi qui croyais qu'en frêle jeune fille **que** je suis, je ne pourrais jamais tirer sur tous ces cordages, j'ai vite été rassurée.
3. Cette maladie tant décriée s'est révélée mortelle dans les cas **où les filles avaient entièrement cessé de s'alimenter.**

**Mes réponses**

1. subordonnée relative, complément du nom *revues*
2. subordonnée relative, complément du nom *fille*
3. subordonnée relative, complément du nom *cas*

Pour le #1 et 2, j'ai de la difficulté à choisir entre groupe pronominal ou subordonnée relative. Dans le #3, je n'hésite pas à prendre subordonnée relative  parce que j'ai une phrase complète avec un verbe dans ce groupe de mots donc c'est clairement une subordonnée.

Pour le #1 & 2, j'ai seulement le subordonnant, je n'ai pas de verbe dans mon groupe de mots à analyser, alors ça me donne envie de les classer simplement comme groupes pronominaux.

**EDIT :**

J'ai eu deux erreurs dans mon devoir. Il a indiqué des erreurs pour #1 et #2, il dit que ce sont des groupes pronominaux et non des subordonnées relatives puisque le groupe ne contient pas de verbe…

Comment: Nous n'avons pour l'instant pas de politique au sujet des questions de leçons, mais nombres d'autres sites du réseau préfèrent donner une explication générale au lieu de réponses directes dans le but d'aider les élèves à mieux comprendre. Voici la [politique du site sur la langue anglaise](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/333/how-to-deal-with-homework-questions). Je crois que nous devrions nous doter une politique sous peu.

Comment: Bonjour Kareen, je suis utilisateur des stack exchanges en math et en informatique alors je comprends bien la mentalité. J'ai passé 2 heures avec ma conjointe sur mon devoir et nous avons fait de notre mieux. Nous avons regardé des explications générales ainsi que mes notes de cours, mais nous ne sommes quand meme pas certain. Avec une réponse nous serons capables de comprendre le pattern.

Comment: Le commentaire n'est pas dirigé directement à vous, mais comme il s'agit je crois de la première question de ce type et qu'il n'y avait pas encore de réponse, j'ai laissé le commentaire ici en attendant de mettre quelque chose sur méta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dans les trois phrases, il y a une proposition subordonnée relative. Un exemple de Wikipédia

> Le livre que je préfère <sup>[WP:fr](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Subordination_%28grammaire%29#Les_diff.C3.A9rentes_cat.C3.A9gories_concern.C3.A9es_par_la_subordination)</sup>

c'est exactement dans la même situation que dans #2. Ici « que je préfère » est une proposition subordonnée relative dans laquelle le pronom relatif « que » est le subordonnant et il remplace le nom « livre », qui est le complément d'objet du verbe de la subordonnée « préfère ».

Dans #1 et #2 le mot en gras est donc un *pronom relatif* (donc un *groupe pronominal* réduit à un seul élément) dont la fonction est *complément d'objet* du verbe de la subordonnée. C'est un *complément d'objet **direct*** pour #2 (« je suis une jeune fille ») et un *complément d'objet **indirect*** pour #1 (« les jeunes filles raffolent **des** revues »¹).

Quant à #3, tu as vu juste, il s'agit bien d'une subordonnée relative complément du nom *cas*.

La banque de dépannage linguistique de l'OQLF a [un article](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=subordonnant&T3.x=0&T3.y=0) sur la notion de subordonnant.

---

¹ *des* est la contraction *de les*, c'est donc bien un complément d'object indirect, puisqu'introduit par une préposition

Comment: Voir mon commentaire à la réponse de Gilles pour le dénouement de l'histoire...

Answer (score 2):

Un groupe pronominal est n'importe quel groupe de mots qui comporte un pronom et un complément. (Si le pronom n'a pas de complément, un mathématicien dirait qu'il s'agit d'un groupe pronominal trivial, mais un grammairien a tendance à dire qu'il n'y a pas de groupe.) Le complément peut être une subordonnée relative ou autre chose.

> **Celles dont les filles raffolent** montrent toutes la même chose.
>   Ce magazine ne montre **rien d'inhabituel**.

Une subordonnée relative est une proposition introduite par un complément de subordination et qui qualifie un nom ou un pronom.

> Les revues **dont les filles raffolent** montrent toutes la même chose.
>   Celles **dont les filles raffolent** montrent toutes la même chose.
>   Les revues **que les filles lisent** montrent toutes la même chose.

Attention, *que* n'introduit pas toujours une subordonnée relative. Il peut aussi introduire une [subordonnée conjonctive](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition_subordonn%C3%A9e#Conjonctive) qui est complément (voire sujet) d'un verbe.

> Je vois **que ces images montrent toutes la même chose**.
>   **Que ces images montrent toutes la même chose** n'est pas surprenant.

Le pronom relatif lui-même (**dont**, **que**, **où**, ...) peut être considéré comme un groupe pronominal réduit à un seul mot, mais cette vision est assez spécieuse, d'autant plus qu'un pronom relatif ne peut pas avoir de complément. Il n'a pas de fonction dans la phrase principale, seulement dans la subordonnée.

Chacune des trois phrases citées dans la question comporte une subordonnée relative qui qualifie un nom (« revues », « filles », « cas »). L'une d'entre elles comporte également une subordonnée relative qui fait partie d'un groupe pronominal, sauras-tu la retrouver ?

Comment: Bonjour Gilles, j'ai eu deux erreurs dans mon devoir. Il ma mis mal les #1 et #2, il dit que ce sont des groupe pronominaux et non des subordonnées relatives puisque le groupe ne contient pas de verbe... De plus, il dit qu'une subordonnée relative est **toujours** complément du nom.

Comment: @Dave: la réponse de Gilles n'apporte aucun élément de réponse pour les cas 1 et 2.

Comment: merci, mais je voulais simplement ajouter que j'ai eu mal alors ça aidera peut-être quelqu'un. je vais edit mon post original.

Comment: @Dave Je ne suis pas d'accord avec ton professeur. La question est quelque peu trompeuse. Considérer un pronom relatif comme groupe pronominal est étrange. Par contre je m'était effectivement trompé, une subordonnée relative est toujours complément d'un nom ou d'un pronom.

Comment: Moi, qui, épris de doute, pense qu'un pronom relatif peut avoir un complément, te suggère de bien vouloir reconsidérer la remarque que tu viens d'ajouter :-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Hum. « Épris de doute » est-il bien complément de « qui » et pas de « moi » ? As-tu un Bescherelle sous la main ?

Comment: Non, je sors cet exemple de mon chapeau, mais le « épris de doute » n'a de sens que que dans la relative. Le sortir de là dénaturerait la phrase. C'est pas dur de trouver d'autres exemples dans le même style.